# Project Euler question

Tags: discussion

I have a solution to one of the Project Euler questions that runs wicked slow, and I'd like to ask for suggestions to speed it up. However, the solution required a fair amount of analysis of the problem first. Before posting anything, I'd like to know what is appropriate in terms of providing analysis of the problem in my question.

Comment: According to [this thread](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/634/89), it is allowed to discuss PE problems / ask for solution here on _Mathematica_.SE. This might even be a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an excellent question. It is nice to keep the site tidy.

Perhaps you can split up your question into two parts. One about: is there a name for the techniques I am using, and one about the PE question itself. If you do, you should probably put them both on main. If it is a really theoretical analysis, perhaps http://math.stackexchange.com or another site may be more appropriate for the "background question".

You should realise that a question can always be edited or deleted, or even migrated.

*If you disagree, please downvote, this is meta after all :)*